# How can I confirgure allure with UFT

Tags: allure

I want to configure allure with UFT for customized report but unable to find any clue to start.

I have not tried anything yet as unable to get any lead.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom class in c# and register it on your machines, after that you can call the functions from the custom class in UFT. I have done a similar thing with Extent reports and the details are available below

https://sumeetkushwah.com/2018/04/25/creating-extent-reports-in-uft/

Source code is availble below

https://github.com/sumeet-kushwah/UFT_ExtentReports

Extent reports are also pretty good. If you don't want to write the code then you can use the extent reports code from above.